# Сортировка строк и UTF-8 в postgresql

Tags: postgresql, база-данных

Добрый день. Сейчас сталкнулся с такой ситуацией: при сортировке строк по имени, слова, начинающиеся с символов вроде таких: Ö оказываются в самом конце:
...
Zypern
Österreich.

Используется такой запрос: SELECT * FROM COUNTRY ORDER BY NAME;
Как бы изменить этот запрос чтобы слова, которые начинаются с символа Ö были сразу после слов, начинающихся с символа O. Желательно бы менять часть после ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/collation.html